# Why is virtualenvwrapper not adding my environment location to my $PATH

Tags: python, linux, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to create a django project, using virtualenvwrapper to isolate/sandbox different projects.

Here are the commands I typed so far ...

```
memyself@somebox:~/path/to/foo_project$ mkvirtualenv foo
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/memyself/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/memyself/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/memyself/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/memyself/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/memyself/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/memyself/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/memyself/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/get_env_details
```

I then installed django in the foo env:

```
(foo) memyself@somebox:~/path/to/foo_project$ pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-1.10.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: django
Successfully installed django-1.10.3
```

I then proceed to attempt to create a django website by entering the following commands:

```
(foo) memyself@somebox:~/path/to/foo_project.foo$ python django-admin.py startproject mysite
python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(foo) memyself@somebox:~/path/to/foo_project.foo$
```

Not believing what I was seeing, I decide to run a few checks, to make sure I'm not going mad  ...

```
(foo) memyself@somebox:~/path/to/foo_project.foo$ pip list --format=legacy
Django (1.10.3)
pip (9.0.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
wheel (0.29.0)


(foo) memyself@somebox:~/path/to/foo_project.foo$ pip show django
Name: Django
Version: 1.10.3
Summary: A high-level Python Web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.
Home-page: http://www.djangoproject.com/
Author: Django Software Foundation
Author-email: foundation@djangoproject.com
License: BSD
Location: /home/memyself/.virtualenvs/foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: 


(foo) memyself@somebox:~/path/to/foo_project.foo$ which django-admin.py
/home/memyself/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/django-admin.py
```

I'm using a simple heuristic that the guy(s?) who created and maintain virtualenvwrapper is(are) much smarter than I am - however, not (automagically) adding the newly created environment to the path, reeks of incompetence bordering on malice.

It is highly unlikely (no, impossible) that the developer/mainteners are that incompetent - which leaves the only possible explanation to be that I'm missing something obvious and doing something foolish.

SO (pun unintended) - **WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?!**

Why can't I simply execute `python djan-admin.py startproject xxx` after creating a new virt environment using virtualenvwrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run `python django-admin.py` (in fact you shouldn't), just run `django-admin.py`. `python` isn't searching your `$PATH`; it's going to look for the file in the current directory. So long as `django-admin.py` has its execute bit set, you can use it as a command without explicitly running `python`.

It also installs itself as `django-admin`, so you can make the command line a little cleaner:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

You don't need the `.py` extension.

The underlying reason is that virtualenv modifies `$PATH`, which is what your shell (bash or whatever) uses to locate the command to execute. When you run `python foo.py`, the command is `python`, and `$PATH` is searched for that. `foo.py` is just a command argument, and your shell doesn't look for that at all. When `python` runs, it looks for `foo.py` in the current directory (and also accepts a relative path like `../otherdir/foo.py` or an absolute path like `/home/someone/foo.py`); it doesn't care about `$PATH` at all.

Comment: Damn! ... You know, I didn't believe you, so I tried both commands you suggested, and both worked!. What kind of sorcery is this?! ;). I searched scores of tutorials online to see an example that shows how to create a django project using **virtualenvwrapper** - couldn't find one, and I didn't want to "pollute" my workspace with the environment files - you saved the day. You deserve a +1 just for that! Thanks also, for the detailed explanation ...Doh!  it's been a long day, on 4 hours sleep.. ;)